# function call among different classes

Tags: java

I have three separate classes that are login.java, LiveMonitoring.java, and HandleMultipleClients.java. Following is the code of all respective classes

Login.java

```
 try
            {
                serverSock = new ServerSocket(2101);
                while (true) 
                {
                    sock = serverSock.accept();
                    HandleMultipleClients hmc=new HandleMultipleClients();
                    hmc.Connect(sock); 
                }
```

HandleMultipleClients.java

```
public class HandleMultipleClients
{
    Map<Integer, java.net.Socket> clients = new HashMap<Integer, java.net.Socket> ();
    Socket soc;
    ServerSocket serverSock;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    DataInputStream dis;
    public HandleMultipleClients()
    {

    }
    public void Connect(Socket sock)
    {
        soc=sock;
        clients.put(soc.getPort(), soc);
    }
    public void messagetospecificclients(String ipaddress,String choice) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.print(ipaddress+"\n"+choice);
        for (Iterator<Integer> iter = clients.keySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
        {
            System.out.print("ok1");
            int key = iter.next();
            java.net.Socket client = clients.get(key);
            InetAddress zee = client.getInetAddress();
            String s = zee.getHostAddress();
            System.out.print(s);
            if (zee.getHostAddress().equals(ipaddress))
            {
                System.out.print("ok2");
                dos =new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeUTF(choice);
            }
```

LiveMonitoring.java

```
HandleMultipleClients hmc=new HandleMultipleClients();
        try
        {
            hmc.messagetospecificclients("192.168.1.102","apps");
        }
```

Now the problem is when i call hmc.messagetospecificclients("192.168.1.102","apps"); it goes to the HandleMultipleClients class and just print the IPaddress and apps but it is not going through the for loop.Kindly tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You never call connect on the `HandleMultipleClients` you create in LiveMonitoring, so it doesn't have anything in its client map.

Comment: but i have called connect in login .java so it should store the client in a list and then by simply traversing through for loop i should access that client through LiveMonitoring class @azurefrog

Comment: What do `Login.java` and `LiveMonitoring.java` have to do with each other?  It looks like you're adding "clients" to one instance of `HandleMultipleClients`, but then trying to use them from another instance?  That second instance doesn't have any "clients".  It was just created on the previous line and `.Connect()` was never called on it.

Comment: You called connect on the one in Login, and then you created a new one in LiveMonitoring, and there you didn't call connect.  The code you posted in Login.java clearly creates its `HandleMultipleClients` as a local variable and never passes that instance to your LiveMonitoring class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an instance of the object and adding a "client" to it here:

```
HandleMultipleClients hmc=new HandleMultipleClients();
hmc.Connect(sock);
```

But you never call `messagetospecificclients()` on that instance.

Then you create another instance and call that method here:

```
HandleMultipleClients hmc=new HandleMultipleClients();
try
{
    hmc.messagetospecificclients("192.168.1.102","apps");
}
```

But you never called `Connect()` on *that* instance to add clients to it.

(As an analogy... Imagine that you have two identical cars.  Same make, same model, came off the same production line.  You have put gas in one of those cars.  And you're trying to drive the other one.  But you can't, because it doesn't have gas in it.)

Call `messagetospecificclients()` on the instance which has the values that have been set:

```
HandleMultipleClients hmc=new HandleMultipleClients();
hmc.Connect(sock);
try
{
    hmc.messagetospecificclients("192.168.1.102","apps");
}
```